# How can I give input with getpass to a Flask app when deploying with uWSGI?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, gunicorn

I have a Flask app that has some cryptographic components. Specifically, there is a key on disk that is encrypted, and must be unencrypted in memory for use during the Flask app processes. In order to unencrypt the key, the user is prompted to enter a passphrase with getpass when the application runs.

This works great with `app.run()` and a single foreground Flask WSGI server. The problem we're running into is that when deploying with uWSGI, the uWSGI controller does not allow stdin.

Ideally, what we would like to happen is similar to when you restart or start Apache or Nginx with SSL - before the service forks it prompts for a password on stdin.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**

Although we still would prefer to use uWSGI, we have moved to gunicorn because of gunicorn's pre-fork options. This solution is still not ideal, especially because we do not have the ability to add a monitoring service like UPSTART. Essentially, we have a script that we run before that uses `read` to set the password into an environment variable and pass that environment variable to the gunicorn app.

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="baz"                                  # Name of the application
APPDIR=/var/apps/baz                        # Application project directory
SOCKFILE=/var/apps/baz/gunicorn.sock        # Using a socket
BIND="127.0.0.1:8000"                       # Using a port
USER="www-data"                             # User to run as
GROUP="www-data"                            # Group to run as
WORKERS=1                                   # How many worker processes

echo "Starting $NAME"

# Collect the passphrase
read -s -p "Enter $NAME passphrase: " PASSPHRASE
echo ""

# Activate the virtual environment
source /var/venvs/baz/bin/activate
export BAZ_SETTINGS="baz.conf.Config"
export BAZ_PASSPHRASE=$PASSPRHASE

# Start Gunicorn
exec gunicorn $NAME:app \
    --user $USER --group $GROUP \
    --bind $BIND \
    --workers $WORKERS \
    --chdir $APPDIR \
    --env BAZ_PASSPHRASE=$PASSPHRASE \
    --daemon
```

This is more or less the script used in the tutorial [Setting up Django with Nginx, Gunicorn, virtualenv, supervisor and PostgreSQL](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) - modified for reading the passphrase and for use with Flask.

We have checked to make sure that the `BAZ_PASSPHRASE` environment variable does not exist in any environments, but this still feels a little squeaky, so we'd still appreciate any comments, particularly with regards to uWSGI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `--honour-stdin` it will disable the remapping of file descriptor 0 to `/dev/null`

if you call `--daemonize` you will lose controlling terminal, so you have to postpone daemonization after the input has been read using `--daemonize2`

Comment: We actually did try this- and I'll get back to you with the reason it didn't work on monday when I can re-evaluate what happened with this argument. One major concern is from the [mod_wsgi docs](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Reading_From_Standard_Input) - that the server might actually read requests from the server in stdin. We need a portable way to give stdin before uWSGI forks the child Flask processes.

Comment: Also, today we're going to test adding --daemons-honour-stdin from the chats posted on [botbot.me](https://botbot.me/freenode/uwsgi/2013-04-08/)

Comment: not sure to follow you, --honour-stdin is the right option to allow workers to manage stdin, just be sure to not "daemonize" uWSGI as it will lose the controlling terminal. I do not understand the pre-fork part of gunicorn as uWSGI allows you to choose when to call fork() (--lazy-apps for having the same behaviour of gunicorn)

Comment: I have update the answer to clarify the daemonization behaviour

Comment: Ok, I buy that - the [documentation for daemonize2](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#daemonize2) says this is more for logging, but for now it looks like it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Use FIFOs instead of STDIN to provide input**

```
#!/bin/sh

FIFO=/tmp/.appfifo
rm -f ${FIFO}
mkfifo ${FIFO}
cat > ${FIFO} # decryt password | /etc/init.d/app start

exec gunicorn $NAME:app \
    --user $USER --group $GROUP \
    --bind $BIND \
    --workers $WORKERS \
    --chdir $APPDIR \
    --env ENCRYPTED_CFG=/etc/app.encrypted.cfg
    --daemon
```

and somewhere in the code

```
get_password(file(os.getenv('ENCRYPTED_CFG'),'r').read())
```